# Convergence of Cantor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that for every nonnegative real number $x$, there is a series (called Cantor series) with $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{c_k}{k!}$$ where $c_k$ are integers such that $0 \leq c_{k+1} \leq k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$

Note: By defining $c_1$ to be the largest integer $\leq x$, $0 \leq x - c_1 < 1$. Thus we can assume that $x \in [0,1)$.

Any hints or a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @AndréNicolas $c_1=47$, $c_k=0$ otherwise?

Comment: Thanks, I missed the $k+1$ subscript.

Comment: Why do you call it Cantor series?

Comment: I do not know the motivation or the history behind it. It is defined that way in Analysis I by Herbert Amann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Continue as you started. For each $k\ge 2$ let $c_k \in [0, k-1] \cap \mathbb N$ largest with $x_k := \sum_{l=1}^k \frac{c_l}{l!} \le x$. Proof (by induction) that $x - x_k \le \frac 1k$.

Comment: @awllower Yes, you are right. Edited, thx.

Comment: I think your last inequality ought to be replaced by $x-x_k\le\frac{1}{(k)!}$. Because, under this assumtion, we would have $\begin{cases}c_{k+1}=i&x\ge x_k+\frac{i}{(k+1)!} \text{ and } x\lt x_k+\frac{i+1}{(k+1)!}\\c_{k+1}=k&x\ge x_k+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}\end{cases}$, for $0\le i\le k-1$. Hence $x-x_{k+1}\begin{cases}\lt \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\\ \le \frac{1}{k!}-\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\end{cases}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @martini Thanks. I solved it.

Comment: I would like to mention a recursive formula for $c_k$. 
Set $x_1 = 0$. Then,
$$c_k = \lfloor k!(x - x_{k-1}) \rfloor $$
This arises from the proof given by martini.